# android navigration drawer with multiple icons

Tags: android, menu, android-actionbar, slider, navigation-drawer

I'm currently trying to modify the UI of an existing Android application by making some slight changes. One change I need to implement is to modify the navigation drawer / slider toggle icon between one of 3 icons (on, off, 'special'). You supply the icon on creation of the ActionBarDrawerToggle on instantiation and there doesn't seem to be a method to modify the value after the object is created. Does anyone know if it's possible to achieve this (hack or no hack) ?

Thanks in advance,
thisguy

Answer (score 0):

Check out this guide here: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

and here: http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html

I think you may change icon on ActionBarDrawerToggle's methods:

```
/** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely closed state. */
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(view);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        /** Called when a drawer has settled in a completely open state. */
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
```

Comment: fantastic - thanks very much for your quick response Melihcan. I'll definitely look into this now and get back to you asap! I appreciate your response!

Comment: This response does not respond to that question =$ ... neither in links attachments neither in the code answer it's said as changing actionBar icon